# Rstudio converts Header(title) into numeric (NA) which I don't want

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a problem with converting chr to numeric. It also applies the command to the header which I really didn't ask for. Please see the image below. My purpose is to keep titles like 'Species', 'sex','age' on but not to change NA value. Can i add an exception for these texts? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Please see the NA, created by an error which I cannot fix. I just wanted it to remain with its title name, any advice?

[image]

Comment: You cannot have some values of a variable be numeric and some strings - you have to pick a format.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try `colnames(Sparrows) <- Sparrows[1,]` and `Sparrows <- Sparrows[-1,]` before converting the rows. The first row of your data contains the column names which you don't want to be there.

Comment: How do you import the data into R? Usually there is a header or column name argument, e.g. `readr::read_csv("filename.csv", col_names = TRUE)` which may help you with your problem.

Comment: I think Julian's comment is on the mark: however you are reading this in is missing the fact that headers are present. If you're using `read.table` or one of its sibling functions (or `readr::read_*` or `data.table::fread` or `vroom::vroom`), you should be reading in headers. However, once you follow MartinGal's advice to *recover* the headers and remove them from the data portion of your frame, you will likely want to do `Sparrows[] <- lapply(Sparrows, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)` to convert strings to numbers, etc.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.